# How to force VueJS not to produce a "*, ::after, ::before" element in css

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I we have a website fully coded in **Sapui5**. We decided to start and slowly replace parts of the website but also develop all new features of the website in **Vue.js**. That was easy so far, because Vue just needs a div element in which the js scripts are sourced. So far everything worked good!

The problem though is that after building/minification, the CSS that is produced contains a

```
*, ::before ::after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

rule, which affects of course the rest of the website.

Is there any way to force Vue.js to avoid creating this on global scale but class specific? I use **Vuetify** and **vue-cli** to build.

Comment: if it is a vue app you would have a index.html file either there you can apply the css you want or override the css in the css file for your index.vue as well both will work.

Comment: You could search for `box-sizing: inherit;` and see if is referenced in the project it self, else it si probably Vuetify, then you could override it with setting `box-sizing: initial;`. Just a thought, why would you remove it? :)

Comment: I checked on the developer console of firefox and I see that this rule comes from the app.css. I tried to override it in App.vue as suggested but then causes problems with the Vuetify elements. More specifically the rest of the website is using `box-sizing: content-box` while Vuetify is using `box-sizing: border-box`.

Comment: @PatroklosSamaras That you leaves you with two options. Either throw out Vuetify or change the rest of the app to use `box-sizing: border-box;`. The second option is what I belive would be the recommendation from most developers. That is why it's soo widely used in the community. Depending on the scale of your app but changing to `border-box: box-sizing;` and adjusting the `width` and `border-box: content-box;` on the elements that need it.

Comment: @Dejan.S thanks a lot. I will go with the second, too. If you could add your comment as an answer to vote for it so that the moderators can close the question, it would be perfect!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`box-sizing: border-box;` is super nice in that you don't have to think if that you have a width set to the element, and let's say you add padding or a border, it "grows internally" so it wont break your layout. This is a wanted and useful in beviour in many situations. If you want to learn exactly why I could post a better scenario explaining? To get to the point :)

You could do either of these

**1)**
Throw out Vuetify and keep using `border-box: content-box;`

**2) (recommended)**
Change the rest of the app to use `box-sizing: border-box;`. This is the option in what I belive would be the recommendation from most developers. That is why it's soo widely used in the community. Depending on the scale of your app but changing to `border-box: box-sizing;` and adjusting the `width` and `border-box: content-box;` on the elements that need it.